# How would I offset a pandas column of data by different amounts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting some columns within a `pandas` dataframe using `matplotlib`. I have a strategy for plotting whereby I'm zeroing to the initial value and then offset each chosen variable by a set amount. For example, this is my current plotting method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# data is in a dataframe called inputData
timeseries_plots=['var1','var3','var8']
offsetFactor = 20

for ii,var in enumerate(timeseries_plots)
    offsetRef = inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0]
    ax.plot(inputData[TimeIndex], offsetFactor*(len(timeseries_plots_avg)-ii-1)+inputData[timeseries_plots_avg[ii]]-offsetRef, label=var,markersize=1,marker='None',linestyle = 'solid',color=colour)
plt.show()
```

This produces something like this (with some `matplotlib` finessing):
[image: constant offset value]

As you can see, it removes the `offsetRef` (which in this case is the initial value of the variable), and then adds a constant `offsetFactor` (equal to 20 in this case) to each variable. The result is lines which start vertically offset by 20.

However, this can be a problem when the values start to drift over time, and one variable might cross another. What I'd like to do is reset the vertical offset - such as by changing the offsetRef beyond a certain date.

I have tried to do this in the following way. I start by initialising an array equal to the size of the variable. I then fill it with the `offsetRef` recalculated at the `resetDates`. I've included comments marked `#PSEUDOCODE` where I'm roughly writing what I want to do - but sorry in advance for them being pretty rough. Thank you in advance!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
inputData = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 5)), columns=['timestamp','var2','var3','var4','var5'])
inputData['timestamp'][:]=pd.date_range('2020-may-01','2020-aug-08')
timeseries_plots=['var1','var3','var4']
offsetFactor = 20
resetDates = ['2020-jun-23','2020-jul-05']

for ii,var in enumerate(timeseries_plots)
    offsetRef = np.zeros(inputData[var].size)
    for tt,ttdate in enumerate(resetDates):
        if tt=0:
        #PSEUDO CODE: offsetRef[ inputData['timestamp'] <resetDates[tt]] = inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0]
        #PSEUDO CODE: offsetRef[ inputData['timestamp'] >=resetDates[tt]] = inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[ttdate]
    #PSEUDO CODE: offsetRef[ inputData['timestamp'] >=resetDates[tt]] = inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[ttdate]
    
    ax.plot(inputData[TimeIndex], offsetFactor*(len(timeseries_plots_avg)-ii-1)+inputData[timeseries_plots_avg[ii]]-offsetRef, label=var,markersize=1,marker='None',linestyle = 'solid',color=colour)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the current solution that I'll stick here so that it might be useful to others:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set up df
inputData = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 5)), columns=['timestamp','var2','var3','var4','var5'])
inputData['timestamp'][:]=pd.date_range('2020-may-01','2020-aug-08')
inputData['var2']=np.arange(0,100,1)
inputData['var2'][0:3]=49
inputData['var4']=np.arange(0,200,2)
inputData['var2'][0:3]=np.nan
# set constants and settings
dispFactor=20
timeseries_plots=['var2','var4']
resetDates=['2020-05-05','2020-05-20', '2020-08-04']
offsetFactor = dispFactor
#begin
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
for ii,var in enumerate(timeseries_plots):
    offsetRef = np.zeros(inputData[var].size)
    for tt,ttdate in enumerate(resetDates):
        if tt==0:        
            if inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate].isna().bool(): #if date is nan
                print('a',inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0],inputData[var].bfill().loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate])
                offsetRef[(inputData['timestamp']<ttdate)]= inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0]
                offsetRef[(inputData['timestamp']>=ttdate)]=inputData[var].bfill().loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate]
            else:
                print('b',inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0],inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate])
                offsetRef[(inputData['timestamp']<ttdate)]= inputData[var].loc[~inputData[var].isnull()].iloc[0]
                offsetRef[(inputData['timestamp']>=ttdate)]= inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate]
        else:
            if inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate].isna().bool(): #if date is nan
                print('c')
                offsetRef[ inputData['timestamp'] >=resetDates[tt]] = inputData[var].bfill().loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate]
            else:
                print('d',inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate])
                offsetRef[ inputData['timestamp'] >=resetDates[tt]] = inputData[var].loc[inputData['timestamp']==ttdate]
        print(offsetRef)
    ax.plot(inputData['timestamp'], offsetFactor*(len(timeseries_plots)-ii-1)+inputData[var]-offsetRef)

plt.show()
```

This 'resets' the offset to 20 at the chosen `resetDates` to produce the following figure:
[image: example of resetting the offset]

I possibly don't need the if-logic catches for nan data (and just rely on `.bfill()`) to work in either case - but this makes me feel that it's safer. I will edit as I improve the solution.